# How to take negation when two or more conditions are true

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below table each row represent a condition. What I'm trying to get is if a given condition is true I would require to get the negation of it. 
The problem I have is that when I get the negation some of the required data is getting removed.

The method what I tried is as follows.

Please find the query below which I have wrote.

```
s_r d_m c_m o_s b_s d_w r_n
SW  SW  DM  A   A       35RE%
SW  SW  DM  B   B       35RE%
SW  SW  DM      B   A   
SW  SW  DM      A   B   

EB  SW  DM  A   A       35RE%
EB  SW  DM  B   B       35RE%
EB  SW  DM      B   A   
EB  SW  DM      A   B   


SELECT *
  FROM e_t t1
 WHERE ( (t1.a_date >= '16-Mar-2018' AND t1.a_date <= '31-Mar-2018')
        OR (t1.r_date >= '16-Mar-2018' AND t1.r_date <= '31-Mar-2018'))
       AND t1.a_m = 'NO'
       AND ( (    t1.s_r IN ('EB', 'PH', 'PT', 'SW')
              AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
              AND t1.c_m = 'SW')
            OR (t1.s_r IN ('PH', 'PT') AND t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
            OR (    (t1.s_r = 'EB' AND t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
                AND (b_s != 'A' AND d_w != 'B')
                AND (b_s != 'B' AND d_w != 'A'))
            OR ( (    t1.s_r = 'SW'
                  AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
                  AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
                  AND t1.d_w NOT IN ('A', 'B'))
                AND o_s != 'A'
                AND r_n != '35RE%'))
```

Update on Request

Below query is designed based on the first row of the above table.

```
SELECT * FROM  e_t t1 WHERE t1.s_r = 'SW'
         AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
         AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
         AND t1.d_w IN ('A', 'B')



A_M S_R D_M C_M B_S D_W
NO  SW  SW  DM  A   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  A   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  A   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  B   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  B   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  B   A
NO  SW  SW  DM  B   A
```

By the negation I meant, I do not want this result to appear in my final result. For that what I did was the following.

```
SELECT * FROM  e_t t1 WHERE t1.s_r = 'SW'
         AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
         AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
         AND t1.d_w **NOT** IN ('A', 'B')
```

Hope the above explanation clear your doubts.

```
Update 27/04/2018
```

Thanks to everyone who helped so far. Based on Ponder Stibbons, i have updated the query as follows. But this query is removing 5 required data rows while fetching rest correctly.

As per the condition table below, I want to take the negation and used the following.

```
s_r d_m c_m o_s b_s d_w r_n
EB  SW  DM      B   A   
EB  SW  DM      A   B   

 (s_r, d_m, c_m, b_s, d_w)      not in 
    (('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'B', 'A'),('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'B'))
```

But this removes the following data set. Which I can't figure out why.

```
s_r d_m c_m o_s b_s d_w r_n
EB  SW  DM          A
```

Furthermore, since I couldn't solve the below,

`(s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not in (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'A', '35RE%')`)

I used a seperate query and took the MINUS from the main set.

Comment: Edit your question and explain what "condition" and "negation" mean.  I just see a table with a bunch of columns and rows.  Desired results would help.

Comment: `'16-Mar-2018'` is **NOT** a date - it is a string literal. If you want to compare dates use date literals `DATE '2018-03-16'` then you will find your code doesn't appear to randomly break when you move to another locale and the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` changes and breaks the implicit conversion Oracle is silently performing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you could use this:

```
select * 
  from eft_txn_details 
  where (s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not in (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'A', '35RE'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not in (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'B', 'B', '35RE'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, b_s, d_w)      not in (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'B', 'A'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, b_s, d_w)      not in (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'B'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not in (('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'A', '35RE'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not in (('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'B', 'B', '35RE'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, b_s, d_w)      not in (('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'B', 'A'))
    and (s_r, d_m, c_m, b_s, d_w)      not in (('EB', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'B'))
```

Add conditions for dates, etc. You could simplify this syntax, but this way it's easier to read, at least for me.

Comment: This got me closer to the desires result. 
Seems I missed the 35RE% thing on the original condition table. 
If r_n starts with 35RE then that has to be removed as well. I tried the NOT LIKE option using the same pattern that you have given above but ended up with an error.

I tried the following to capture this,
<pre>
(s_r, d_m, c_m, o_s, b_s, r_n) not like (('SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'A', 'A', '35RE%'))</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ponder Stibbons I was able to get the desired results but I'm not sure whether it's the best way. If any one can suggest something better, really aprpecaite it.

```
/* Formatted on 27/04/2018 11:19:46 AM (QP5 v5.150) */
SELECT *
  FROM e_t t1
 WHERE ( (t1.a_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
              AND t1.a_date <= '31-Mar-2018')
            OR (t1.r_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
                AND t1.r_date <= '31-Mar-2018'))
       AND t1.a_c = 'NO'
       AND ( (    t1.s_r IN ('EB', 'PH', 'PT', 'SW')
              AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
              AND t1.c_m = 'SW')
            OR (    t1.s_r IN ('PH', 'PT')
                AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
                AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
            OR (    t1.s_r = 'EB'
                AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
                AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
                AND (t1.b_s, t1.d_w) NOT IN
                        ( ('B', 'A')))
            OR (    t1.s_r = 'SW'
                AND t1.d_m = 'SW'
                AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
                AND t1.d_w NOT IN ('A', 'B')))

MINUS
(SELECT *
   FROM e_t t1
  WHERE ( (t1.a_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
               AND t1.a_date <= '31-Mar-2018')
             OR (t1.r_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
                 AND t1.r_date <= '31-Mar-2018'))
        AND a_c IN ('AC', 'NO')
        AND s_r IN ('EB', 'SW')
        AND d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
        AND c_m = 'DM'
        AND (o_s,s_w) IN
                (( 'A', 'A'))
        AND r_n LIKE '35RE%'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT *
   FROM e_t t1
  WHERE ( (t1.a_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
               AND t1.a_date <= '31-Mar-2018')
             OR (t1.r_date >= '16-Mar-2018'
                 AND t1.r_date <= '31-Mar-2018'))
        AND a_c = 'NO'
        AND s_r = 'EB'
        AND d_m = 'SW'
        AND c_m = 'DM'
        AND (t1.b_s, t1.d_w) IN
                ( ('A', 'B'))
     )
```